# A way to encrypt my files from editing in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt my folder and my files from editing in Ubuntu?

I want a way to protect my folder and content from editing, but I want to allow access to the files without giving authority to edit or delete. Here I am referring to the file permissions however I that only I can change them with authority or administer.

One way is to go properties, read and write properties; but as my institute uses a common computer, and allows only a common account, it can be easily changed.

Is there a way to password-protect my files from editing, while allowing it to be view and accessed by anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different questions - file permissions and encryption.  But your description of the use case indicates only file permissions.  So I'll answer both :)

Ubuntu does have the option of encrypting home directories during install, or at least the user that is created during the install process.  Unfortunately, to do it after install you need to be the root user and NOT logged in to the account that will be encrypted.

https://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/

But that will also block access to everyone on the system, because they won't be able to decrypt anything.

The default permissions - 755 for directories and 644 for files - does exactly what you want. Be aware that there are some sensitive files that you do want to protect - your `~/.ssh` directory, Firefox or Chrome/Chromium profile, etc. and you'll want to change the permissions on those to 750 or 700 for directories and 640 or 600 for files.

Comment: Root privileges are not available for the  account nor I can create a second account.  Is there another way?

Comment: @unknownuser you got me mid-edit... please re-read answer and edit your question if you need to clarify

Comment: I am referring to file permissions that is read or write but I want that only I or admister can change them.Is there that will authority verification like password to allow changes to that  but at the same time allow all to access the files as I can get into trouble if I don't.

Comment: Yes, the default file permissions make anyone not your user or in your user's primary group have read-only access.